# Correct approach to pass data around between class dependencies

Tags: c#

I have the following `MyModel` class:

```
public class MyModel {
    public string OtherProp {get;set;}
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

Which gets instantiated in the following `Invoker` class's `Execute` method. `Invoker` class has two dependencies, both of which have a `RunFunc` method that take `MyModel` as a parameter.

```
public class Invoker() {
    private readonly IMyDependency1 _dep1;
    private readonly IMyDependency2 _dep2;

    public Invoker(IMyDependency1 dep1, IMyDependency2 dep2){
        _dep1 = dep1;
        _dep2 = dep2;
    }

    public void Execute() {
        var model = new MyModel(){
            OtherProp = "Hi"
        }

        _dep1.RunFunc(model);

        // This RunFunc uses the Prop1 property set by MyDependency1's RunFunc
        _dep2.RunFunc(model);
    }
}
```

The first dependency, `MyDependency1` updates the incoming `MyModel` with `Prop1`

```
public class MyDependency1(): IMyDependency1 {
    public void RunFunc(MyModel model) {
        // do some work

        // update model
        model.Prop1 = "New prop 1"
    }
}
```

This then gets used in `MyDependency2` class' `RunFunc` method as shown below:

```
public class MyDependency2(): IMyDependency2 {
    public void RunFunc(MyModel model) {
        // do some work using model.Prop1
        var prop = model.Prop1
    }
}
```

My question: Is this a good way to pass data around between dependencies of a class (`Invoker` in my example) or are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: too abstract to see what you are actually trying to do. So hard to say. Plus You dont show IDependency1 and IDependency2

Comment: My favorite construct for invoking things indirectly are storing and or passing around `Actions<>` and `Funcs<>`

Comment: If this Update/DoWork model works then its fine. If you wanted to have a more generic and futureproof model from the start you may look at pipelines, but that could be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

A problem of your approach is that it is hard to see that `_dep1.RunFunc` manipulates the `MyModel` variable. What would happen, if someone would interchange the two method calls by accident? If an exception with a clear message (like "call _dep1.RunFunc first!") was thrown immediately, this was fine. But I also could imagine that this could lead to more subtle bug. If you want to show that `_dep1.RunFunc` manipulates `MyModel`, you could return it:

```
public class MyDependency1(): IMyDependency1 {
    public MyModel RunFunc(MyModel model) {
        // do some work

        // update model
        model.Prop1 = "New prop 1"
        return model;
    }
}
```

The `Execute` method of the invoker would look like this:

```
public void Execute() {
        var model = new MyModel(){
            OtherProp = "Hi"
        }

        model = _dep1.RunFunc(model);

        // This RunFunc uses the Prop1 property set by MyDependency1's RunFunc
        _dep2.RunFunc(model);
    }
```

If `MyModel` is a reference type, it this is not necessary, but now for the reader of the code it is clear that `_dep1.RunFunc` manipulates `model` and that it has to be called before `_dep2.RunFunc`.